# XamlParseException when implementing Affdex.ImageListener

Tags: c#, .net, windows, affdex-sdk

When implementing `Affdex.ImageListener` on my main window, I get an `XamlParseException` stating

> The method or operation is not implemented

My `MainWindow` stub implements all the methods of the interface. If I remove the interface, everything is fine. Any pointers or assistance will be greatly appreciated. Code below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, Affdex.ImageListener {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void onImageCapture( Affdex.Frame frame ) {
    }

    public void onImageResults( Dictionary<int, Face> faces, Affdex.Frame frame ) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are missing a namespace definition in

```
Dictionary<int, Face> faces
```

It should be:

```
Dictionary<int, Affdex.Face> faces
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Comment: Possibly the assembly is not imported correctly ? Can u create a variable from any of the classes inside the assembly?

Comment: Should I not be getting a compilation error then, if the Affdex assembly isn't included properly? IntelliSense is picking up all the types in the Affdex namespace.